# Force User to Provide Profile Before Saving in Django Admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

Am trying to force a user to provide a profile before they are saved from the django admin.
here is my profile model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user=models.OneToOneField(AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='profile',primary_key=True)
    #other fields

    def get_user_info(user):
        return UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
    @receiver(post_save, sender=AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
        if created:
            profile = UserProfile(user=instance)
            profile.save()
```

Am using `authtools` so the user profile sender is AUTH_USER_MODEL.
If I add a new user from within admin,they are saved even if they have not provided or filled in the profile.
I want to prevent them from being saved until they fill in the profile fields.
Any insights on how to do this?
Here is my admin.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

from authtools.admin import NamedUserAdmin
from authtools.forms import UserCreationForm

User = get_user_model()


class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    A UserCreationForm with optional password inputs.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].required = False
        self.fields['password2'].required = False
        # If one field gets autocompleted but not the other, our 'neither
        # password or both password' validation will be triggered.
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = super(UserCreationForm, self).clean_password2()
        if bool(password1) ^ bool(password2):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Fill out both fields")
        return password2


class UserAdmin(NamedUserAdmin):
    """
    A UserAdmin that sends a password-reset email when creating a new user,
    unless a password was entered.
    """
    inlines = [ UserProfileInline, ]
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'description': (
                "Enter the new user's name and email address and click save."
                " The user will be emailed a link allowing them to login to"
                " the site and set their password."
            ),
            'fields': ('email', 'name',),
        }),
        ('Password', {
            'description': "Optionally, you may set the user's password here.",
            'fields': ('password1', 'password2'),
            'classes': ('collapse', 'collapse-closed'),
        }),
    )

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change and not obj.has_usable_password():
            # Django's PasswordResetForm won't let us reset an unusable
            # password. We set it above super() so we don't have to save twice.
            obj.set_password(get_random_string())
            reset_password = True
        else:
            reset_password = True

        super(UserAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

        if reset_password:
            reset_form = PasswordResetForm({'email': obj.email})
            assert reset_form.is_valid()
            reset_form.save(
                subject_template_name='registration/account_creation_subject.txt',
                email_template_name='registration/account_creation_email.html',
            )


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: I don't think your signal handler (create_profile_for_new_user) should be under UserProfile.

Comment: Hi Lauri Elias 1 I would prefer if you posted this with what you think works :)

Comment: look to use signals instead, anytime a new auth user is created have it create an auth profile.

Comment: @ChrisHawkers? any example?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a custom middleware and check, if the logged in user has filled out the profile. If not, the middleware would redirect the user to a view, where he can fill out the profile.

Example:

```
class ProfileMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if not request.user.profile:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('create-profile'))
        return None
```

Haven't tested the code, but it should get you started. It's the cleanest way of doing this and it will also force the user to fill out the profile, otherwise he cannot open a page on the website.

Hope this helps.